# How to combine expert rules into decision tree

Tags: machine-learning, cart

There are many classes, and also there is expert rule for each class, for example ,age and student for first class and age and credit-rating for second. Is there any algorithm, that can be used to combine this rules into one decision tree like [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_mining/images/dm_decision_tree.jpg)